# Mustache.js + jQuery: what is the minimal working example ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I would like to use mustache.js with jQuery in my HTML5 app, but I can't make all the component work together. Every file is found, there is no problem here (the template is loaded roght, I can see its value in the Firebug debugguer).

Here is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.mustache.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var template = $.get('../templates/article.mustache');
    $.getJSON('../js/article.json', function(view) {
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, view);
        $("#content").append(html);
    });
});
```

The jquery.mustache.js file is the one generated from https://github.com/janl/mustache.js :

```
/*
Shameless port of a shameless port
@defunkt => @janl => @aq

See http://github.com/defunkt/mustache for more info.
*/

;(function($) {

// <snip> mustache.js code

  $.mustache = function(template, view, partials) {
    return Mustache.to_html(template, view, partials);
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Noting is displayed. Firebug tells me

> Mustache is not defined

See capture :
[image]

I know something is missing, but I can't tell what.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**:
The correct and complete answer to a *minimal* example is the following :

- write the template in the script, do not load it from a file
- idem for the json data
- read how the jQuery is generated and use `$.mustache.to_html` function instead of the (documented on github) `Mustache.to_html` (thanks to [@mikez302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28324/mikez302))
- refactor 'till you drop

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var template = " ... {{title}} ... ";
  var json = {title: "titre article" }
  var article = $.mustache(template, json);
  $("#content").append(article);
});
```

But, it is easy to read the json from another file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var template = " ... {{title}} ... ";
  $.getJSON('../js/article.json', function(view) {
    var article = $.mustache(template, view);
    $("#content").append(article);
  });
});
```

You can finally also read the template from a file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('../js/article.json', function(view) {
    $.get("../templates/article.mustache", function(template) {
      var article = $.mustache(template, view);
      $("#content").append(article);
    });
  });
});
```

Working example (without loading order problems) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('../js/article.json', function(model) { return onJSON(model); });
});

function onJSON(model) {
  $.get("../templates/article.mustache", function(view) {
    var article = $.mustache(view, model);
    $("#content").append(article);
  });
}
```

Comment: I would put all the JavaScript **after** the content.  [LINK](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'm not looking for optimisation right now, I ant to make my code work

Comment: I posted it as a comment and not an answer.  Of course, the **order** in which you load your script includes _also_ matters to making code work.  If you're a beginner at JavaScript, this information is a critical 'must read'.  Do all beginners know they need to load jQuery _before_ they load jQueryUI or any other jQuery plugin?

Comment: @Sparky672 to me it makes sense to load jQuery before any other jQuery related plugin. Thanks for the hint anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In place of `Mustache.to_html`, try `$.mustache`. It looks to me like the `Mustache` variable is defined within the function, so it is not directly accessible outside of it.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question already ahs been answered, however I wrote a blog post on precisely this topic and thought I would share it here so anyone looking for examples of how to use Mustache with jQuery might see it.

http://blog.xoundboy.com/?p=535

Comment: A couple years later so probably to be expected, but i wanted to let you know your blog link is dead.

Comment: @Prefix thanks for the heads up, I only just read this comment from you, sorry for the delay. It's back up now anyway :)