# $.mustache() is defined, but Mustache isn't defined when mustache() is invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, mustache

I am trying to use Mustache along with requireJS and jQuery, and it seems that it is being loaded into the browser since Chrome's console outputs correctly:

```
>$.mustache
<function (template, view, partials) {
    return Mustache.render(template, view, partials);
}
```

But when I try to use the mustache function it gives the error `ReferenceError: Mustache is not defined` and points to line 588 in the mustache.js file itself:

```
$.mustache = function (template, view, partials) {
    return Mustache.render(template, view, partials);
};
```

Here is how I'm invoking it in the main.js file:

```
require(['mustache'], function(Mustache){
    var view = {test:'TEST'};
    var temp = '{{test}}!!!';
    $.mustache(temp,view);
});
```

Comment: well if you test in console, it will work for sure as long as the js is called. If it does not work in code, it's probably because you are trying to use it before the js is called

Comment: check this link hope this is of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439935/mustache-js-jquery-what-is-the-minimal-working-example

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't seem to even be working in the console somehow. `$.mustache` itself is defined as a function, but when I attempt using it it says that `Mustache` isn't defined. And in the source code there doesn't seem to be any sort of definition for it either. Perhaps there's extra source code I'm missing? To my knowledge there's just jquery.mustache.js though which I got from the official site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Problem

Mustache is AMD-aware so when you just load the `mustache.js` file, it detects that it is running with an AMD-loader (RequireJS), calls `define` and does not leak anything into the global space. Yay! This is perfect behavior for an AMD-aware module. And if there is no AMD-loader, it does the typical thing: export a single symbol into the global space (`Mustache`).

However, when you use the jQuery plugin that is available with the Mustache codebase you get an **eldritch abomination**, a creature which is both AMD-aware and yet ignores AMD, which does not leak anything to the global space and yet depends on leaking things to the global space. Basically, what happens is that Mustache's core, which is AMD-aware is wrapped in code that adds the jQuery support but this code is *not* AMD-aware. Altogether, this code will work well only if it is **not** loaded in an environment where there is an AMD-loader present.

The error you get is because while Mustache does not leak anything to the global space, the jQuery plugin expects to find `Mustache` in the global space.

#### Options

There are a number of options open to you:

1. Don't use the jQuery plugin bundled with Mustache.
2. Use ugly RequireJS hacks to make it work. This includes deliberately leaking `Mustache` into the global space. (Yuck!) Declaring a `shim` for the `mustache` module even though it calls `define`. (When I tried it, it worked but I would not bet on this being stable at all, because `shim` is for code that **does not** call `define`.)
3. Wrap the wrapper (ha!) into boilerplate that makes it behave.

#### Getting the Wrapper to Behave

I prefer option 3. This can be automated using Grunt or `make`, `rake`, what-have-you. The recipe is to concatenate 4 files in this order:

1. Code to put before Mustache's jQuery wrapper:

   ```
   (function (factory) {
       // If in an AMD environment, define() our module, else use the
       // jQuery global.
       'use strict';
       if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
           define(['jquery', 'mustache'], factory);
       else
           factory(jQuery, Mustache);
   }(function (jQuery, Mustache) {
       'use strict';
   ```
2. The file `mustache/wrappers/jquery/mustache.js.pre`. This is bundled with Mustache.
3. The file `mustache/wrappers/jquery/mustache.js.post`. This is bundled with Mustache.
4. Code to put after Mustache's jQuery wrapper:

   ```
   }));
   ```

Once these 4 files are combined together in this order, you get a file that you can load with RequireJS.

Here's an example. In the following example, all third party components were installed with Bower. The `js` subdirectory contains the result of concatenating the four files as explained above and this result is named `jquery.mustache.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script id="template" type="text/html">
      <p>Hi, {{name}}</p>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      require.config({
        baseUrl: ".",
        paths: {
          jquery: "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery",
          mustache: "bower_components/mustache/mustache",
          "jquery.mustache": "js/jquery.mustache"
        }
      });
      require(["jquery", "jquery.mustache"], function ($) {
        console.log($.mustache);
        $(document.body).append($("#template").mustache({name: "blah"}));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've run this in Chrome without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

The mustache module does not export a global Mustache object when it is invoked through the CommonJS interface (as require.js does) - it does export this object when the module is included via the  tag, instead.

You can see this on line 23 of the jquery.mustache.js source: 
[jquery.mustache.js (gist)](https://gist.github.com/jamesdarvell/2e2414df9db289249f26#file-jquery-mustache)

The jQuery plugin refers to this global Mustache object, which does not exist when jquery.mustache.js is imported by require.js.

You need to tell require.js to export the Mustache object - this is done through the require.config settings, using a **shim** property:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'mustache': {
        exports: 'Mustache'
    }
  }
});
```

Include this code before the call to **require()**, and the (global) Mustache object will be available to the **$.mustache** function (i.e. it will work).