# Mustache is not defined error in node js : Uncaught error

Tags: javascript, node.js, rendering, render, mustache

I want to render the pages on the client side with `Mustache.js` but it says Mustache is not defined. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419991/mustache-is-defined-but-mustache-isnt-defined-when-mustache-is-invoked) but it's difficult to understand as i just started learning about websites/rendering etc. In order to learn i need to fix this issue but i have no clue how can i do that.

Can someone tell me what do i need to do to fix it without going into much details as i am a beginner in `scripting languages`.

Here is my code: I am trying to open a new page and then simple render it.

```
socket.on('sign-up-succes',(data) => {
  window.open(data.redirect,"_self");
  var template = jQuery('#message-template').html();
  var html = Mustache.render(template,{
    text : "Hello"
   });
  jQuery('#messages').append(html);
});
```

Comment: Hi Khan, did you define first Mustache with the mustache package? `var Mustache = require('mustache')`, I wonder also if it is installed (`npm i mustache`)

Comment: @JorgeValentini yes i did that , it is defined but it is not accessable with `Mustache....`.

Comment: Can you post the line where you defined it? To see the full snippet that fails and reproduce it?

Comment: Can you post the bigger code snippet, it is hard to understand your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you posted I see you are using `window` object, so I believe you are trying to use `Mustache` in the client side script.

If so, then use below CDN:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.0/mustache.js
```

or

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.0/mustache.min.js
```

I suggest you render templates from Server side(Node.js in your case).

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cvqLkb4t/

HTML

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janl/mustache.js/master/mustache.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    socket.on('sign-up-succes',(data) => {
      window.open(data.redirect,"_self");
      var template = jQuery('#message-template').html();
      var html = Mustache.render(template,{
        text : "Hello"
       });
      jQuery('#messages').append(html);
    });
    </script>
```