# Mustache.js template with jquery form validation

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, mustache, jquery-form-validator

I am trying to apply jQuery form validator on the HTML code generated through ajax using `$("#target").html(Mustache.render(template, data))` but it is not working.

The issue is that the jQuery validator is not getting attached to the form in the html code generated by Mustache in ajax call.

Query: Is it even possible to apply jQuery form validation on html code rendered by Mustache.js in ajax-success function?

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/q/6439935/11358033.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mustache.js + jQuery: what is the minimal working example ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439935/mustache-js-jquery-what-is-the-minimal-working-example)